# LLDB launch xcodebuild with xcpretty

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb, xcodebuild

I am launching `xcodebuild` through the `lldb` debugger so I can alter its execution like:

```
lldb

# set debugging target
target create /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild

# launch process and stop at entry point
process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test

# set a breakpoint
breakpoint set -F "+[IDELaunchParametersSnapshot launchParametersWithSchemeIdentifier:launcherIdentifier:debuggerIdentifier:launchStyle:runnableLocation:debugProcessAsUID:workingDirectory:commandLineArgs:environmentVariables:architecture:platformIdentifier:buildConfiguration:buildableProduct:deviceAppDataPackage:allowLocationSimulation:locationScenarioReference:showNonLocalizedStrings:language:region:routingCoverageFileReference:enableGPUFrameCaptureMode:enableGPUValidationMode:debugXPCServices:debugAppExtensions:internalIOSLaunchStyle:internalIOSSubstitutionApp:launchAutomaticallySubstyle:]"

break command add
po $rcx = (unsigned long)IDEDefaultLauncherIdentifier
po $r8 = (unsigned long)IDEDefaultDebuggerIdentifier
continue
DONE

# resume execution
continue
```

What I want to achieve is to attach `xcpretty` to:

```
process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test
```

like

```
process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test || xcpretty
```

but I can see that obviously that is not the way.

```
xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '||'.
```

Any ideas if that is even possible and if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test | xcpretty

instead of

process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test || xcpretty

or you can go this way

process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test  > output.txt

xcpretty < output.txt

Comment: I am getting `xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '>'.` and `xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action '|'.`

Comment: Let me know one thing, is it working 
process launch -s -- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone SE' test 
What's the output for the above command ?

Comment: There is no output it. It just starts the process and stop it right after the execution. It's `lldb` after all..

Comment: Then why did you want to redirect that to xcpretty , xcpretty works only if it gets content from the previous command, if not it can't do anything.
Its just a nice formatter

Comment: The question is whether or not is possible, not why do I want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The run-args in lldb's "process launch" do not support piping or redirection operators.  If the -c option is set, lldb will get the shell to do shell expansion on the arguments.  But that's all the interaction with the shell that lldb supports.

If you need to debug something that is running in a chain of execution, you will have to launch the process chain manually, and attach to the process in the chain after the fact.  The way to do this is to start the attach in lldb before launching your process and use the `-w` option to `process attach` to tell lldb to attach to the process once it starts up.  Then start the process.  Unless your system is heavily loaded lldb will generally catch the process early in its startup, so for most debugging tasks you don't miss code you actually care about.